# Ruby C extension not resolving 3rd party dlls at runtime

Tags: c, ruby, dll, devkit

I have a Ruby C extension that is providing a ruby interface to use a third part C library. I am able to build the library, let's call it something.so just fine. However, it's compiled against the third party .lib and .dll files dynamically.

When I actually try to run a ruby script that has

```
require 'something'
```

it fails. Ruby doesn't know how to find the DLLs the something.so was linked against. It gives me an error like:

```
---------------------------
ruby.exe - System Error
---------------------------
The program can't start because SomeThirdParty.dll is missing from your computer. Try    reinstalling the program to fix this problem. 
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

What do I need to do to tell ruby how to find this dll? If I put all the third party dlls in the same directory as the ruby script I'm running it works, but I'd rather not do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put it in a place that is inside your **PATH**. A good place may be the `ruby\bin` directory.